# Oracle: SQL Error: ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired

Tags: oracle, ddl, ora-00054

I have a simple DDL script: 
First the `DROP TABLE` statements, then the `CREATE` and then the `INSERT`. It worked all the time but all of a sudden I get this error message when running the script:

Error report -

```
SQL Error: ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired
00054. 00000 -  "resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified"
*Cause:    Resource interested is busy.
*Action:   Retry if necessary.
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Is the database is use by other applications at the same time?

Comment: no, i'm just using the SQLDeveloper for this...nothing else is running

Comment: check that the some other sessions have locks on the table. Otherwise, rerun the script.